"Access denied for user 'myuser'@'<my-ip>' (using password: YES)"
I'm trying to create a lambda function that should connect with my Amazon RDS database (MySql Community engine). I configured the auth with IAM. I linked the function and the DB:

I created the user with the AWSAuthenticationPlugin and all the privileges:

The code is a NodeJs 18.x Lambda layer code:
async function connect() {
  try {
    const signer = new Signer({
      hostname: process.env.ENDPOINT,
      port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      username: process.env.DB_USER,
      region: process.env.REGION,
    });

    // Get the authentication token
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
      host: process.env.ENDPOINT,
      port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      ssl: "Amazon RDS",
      authPlugins: {
        mysql_clear_password: () => () =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            signer
              .getAuthToken({
                region: process.env.REGION,
                hostname: process.env.ENDPOINT,
                port: process.env.DB_PORT,
                username: process.env.DB_USER,
              })
              .then((token) => {
                resolve(token);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log("Error getting auth token", err);
                reject(err);
              });
          }),
      },
    });
    return connection;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Error connecting to RDS: ${error}`);
  }
}

and the lambda function interrupts after trying to connect, with error:
Error connecting to RDS: Error: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'<my-ip>' (using password: YES)
Does someone have a hint?
I have read and tried everything on the official documentation, but I found no other code examples or my specific case examples.

Did you configure grants on the RDS database for that user@ip? Are you sure you used the correct password?

This line looks a bit odd: ssl: "Amazon RDS" -- did that come out of some documentation?

@Barmar yes, I follow every docs and I tried to give the user every grants (GRANT USAGE ON .* TO ''@'%';), but the Lambda didn't worked

@JohnRotenstein I found that line on the GitHub issue section of the library mysql2, on the AWS docs I can't find a guide for this node package

All the other languages seem to be referencing an SSL certificate. Examples: Connecting to your DB instance using IAM authentication and the AWS SDK for Python (Boto3) - Amazon Relational Database Service

So, I have updated the script to this:
ssl: {
rejectUnauthorized: true,
ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/certificates/eu-north-1-bundle.pem"),
},
And the user has this configuration:
{
"host" : "%",
"user" : "mouser",
"plugin" : "AWSAuthenticationPlugin",
"ssl_type" : "X509",
"ssl_cipher" : ?,
"x509_issuer" : ?,
"x509_subject" : ?
}
Can you spot a mistake?

I just spent two days on this problem and finally figured out the answer for my case. Turns out for me it wasn't a configuration problem on the database side but rather my connector parameters.
I am using IAM authentication inside a Python Lambda function connecting to an AWS RDS MySQL database using sqlalchemy and pymysql.
DBHostname = DBCLUSTER_HOSTNAME
DBPort = DBCLUSTER_PORT
DBUsername = DBCLUSTER_USER
DBName = DBCLUSTER_NAME

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql:///"
)  # connection params will be set by the event callback

@sqlalchemy.event.listens_for(engine, "do_connect")
def provide_token(dialect, conn_rec, cargs, cparams):
    client = boto3.client("rds")
    token = client.generate_db_auth_token(
        DBHostname=DBHostname,
        Port=int(DBPort),
        DBUsername=DBUsername,
        Region=REGION,
    )

    # set up db connection parameters, alternatively we can get these from boto3 describe_db_instances
    cparams["host"] = DBHostname
    cparams["port"] = int(DBPort)
    cparams["user"] = DBUsername
    cparams["password"] = token
    cparams["database"] = DBName
    cparams["ssl"] = {
        "ca": "ssl-ca-bundle.pem",
        "verify_identity": False,
    }
    cparams["auth_plugin_map"] = {
// this might be the key I was missing - we need to tell the connection we are not using a normal password
        "mysql_clear_password": None,
    }

